# DataTable Jquery How to make the cell resizeable

Tags: jquery, datatable, styling

I am using JQuery datatables.I see that columns width are the same. But I want some column with lower amount of text to be have a narrower width compared to the other one with lots of text. Or at least be able to resize the column width by dragging the column's border. I learnt that there are plug-ins that provide this functionality but none of them worked for me. I was wondering if anyone has any tips. 
here is my html file for creating the table

```
            <table class="table dt-responsive hover order-column cell-border display compact" cellspacing="0" id="dataTable" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="dataTableRow">
                        <th class="id1">ID1</th>

                        <th class="id2">ID2</th>

                        <th class="cellWithToolTip matchingNumber">#Mat.
                         <span class="cellToolTip">Number of Matching Terms</span>
                        </th>
                        <th>Matching Terms</th>

                        <th>Original Terms in Data Source One</th>

                        <th>Original Terms in Data Source Two</th>

                        <th>Acc.
                            <span class="cellToolTip">Accept</span>
                        </th>


                        <th>Dec.
                            <span class="cellToolTip">Decline</span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr class="dataTableRow">
                        <th>ID1</th>

                        <th>ID2</th>

                        <th class="cellWithToolTip">#Mat.
                         <span class="cellToolTip">Number of Matching Terms</span>
                        </th>

                        <th>Matching Terms</th>

                        <th>Original Terms in Data Source One</th>

                        <th>Original Terms in Data Source Two</th>

                        <th class="cellWithToolTip">Acc.
                            <span class="cellToolTip">Accept</span>
                        </th>


                        <th class="cellWithToolTip">Dec.
                            <span class="cellToolTip">Decline</span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

here is my js file

```
  var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({   


    "ajax": {
      "url" : root+"/PVJson",
      "dataSrc" : "records"
    },
    "columns": [
      {
        "data": "id1"
      },
      {
        "data": "id2"
      },
      {
        "data": "matchingTerms",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return data.length;
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "matchingTerms"
      },
      {
        "data": "orginalTermsTable1"
      },
      {
        "data": "orginalTermsTable2"
      },
      {
        "data": "",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<button>+</button>";
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<button>-</button>";
        }
      }

    ],
      "columnDefs":[
          {
              "targets":[6,7],
              "searchable":false,
              "sortable":false

          }           
      ]


  });
```

here is the css file:

```
/*  to create tool tip for table's header*/

.cellWithToolTip{
  position:relative;
}

.cellToolTip{
  display:none;
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:100;
  border:1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#cccccc;
  padding:6px;
  color:#555555; 
  top:20px; 
  left:20px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:lighter;
}

.cellWithToolTip:hover span.cellToolTip{
  display:block;
}

table{table-layout:fixed; width: 100%}
td{width:1px; word-wrap: break-word;}
```

in the following image: there are lots of white space in column 2 and 3 and the last two column that I want to remove.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like below table so u can solve your resize issue

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataTable = $("#datatable").DataTable({
    dom: "<'dt-head clearfix'lrf>t<'dt-foot clearfix'ip>",
    deferRender: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    fixedHeader: true,
    responsive: true,
    language: {
      search: "_INPUT_",
      searchPlaceholder: "Search",
      lengthMenu: "<select>" +
        '<option value="10">10</option>' +
        '<option value="25">25</option>' +
        '<option value="50">50</option>' +
        '<option value="100">100</option>' +
        '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
        "</select> rows per page",
      oPaginate: {
        sNext: "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>",
        sPrevious: "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>"
      }
    }
  });  
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.panel {
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.panel .panel-heading {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dt-head {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
.dt-head .dataTables_length,
.dt-head .dataTables_filter {
  padding: 0;
}
.dt-head .dataTables_length label,
.dt-head .dataTables_filter label {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}
.dt-head .dataTables_length input,
.dt-head .dataTables_filter input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 14px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  min-width: 225px;
  margin: -1px -1px -1px 5px;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.dt-head .dataTables_length input:focus,
.dt-head .dataTables_filter input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.dt-head .dataTables_length select,
.dt-head .dataTables_filter select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 32px;
  margin: -1px 5px -1px -1px;
  min-width: 60px;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.dt-head .dataTables_length select:focus,
.dt-head .dataTables_filter select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table.dataTable {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table.dataTable thead th,
table.dataTable thead td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}
table.dataTable tbody th,
table.dataTable tbody td {
  padding: 6px 10px;
}
table.dataTable th {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}
table.dataTable.no-footer {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd, table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
table.dataTable.fixedHeader-floating.no-footer {
  border-bottom: none;
}
table.dataTable thead th {
  position: relative;
}
table.dataTable thead th.sorting, table.dataTable thead th.sorting_asc, table.dataTable thead th.sorting_desc {
  background-image: none;
}
table.dataTable thead th.sorting:after,
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_asc:after,
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_desc:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 8px;
  display: block;
  font: normal normal normal 12px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
table.dataTable thead th.sorting:after {
  content: "";
  color: #ccc;
}
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_asc:after {
  content: "";
}
table.dataTable thead th.sorting_desc:after {
  content: "";
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_info {
  padding: 10px;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate {
  padding: 0;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button,
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover,
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current,
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
  border: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  min-width: 42px;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #333 !important;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current,
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff !important;
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled,
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover,
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  color: #999 !important;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-foot .dataTables_paginate .ellipsis {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  color: #999;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  min-width: 42px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}

div.dataTables_scrollBody table.dataTable thead th.sorting:after,
div.dataTables_scrollBody table.dataTable thead th.sorting_asc:after,
div.dataTables_scrollBody table.dataTable thead th.sorting_desc:after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Datatable</div>
  <table class="stripe order-column" id="datatable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th class="desktop">Header 2</th>
        <th class="min-tablet-l">Header 3</th>
        <th class="min-tablet-l">Header 4</th>
        <th class="min-tablet-l">Header 5</th>
        <th class="desktop">Header 6</th>
        <th class="desktop">Header 7</th>
        <th>Header 8</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell A</td>
        <td>Table Cell B</td>
        <td>Table Cell C</td>
        <td>Table Cell D</td>
        <td>Table Cell E</td>
        <td>Table Cell F</td>
        <td>Table Cell G</td>
        <td>Table Cell H</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I ran your code and I still don't get to resize columns. Columns are divided equally and no way to resize the columns.